# How to use different attributes in inherited objects in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, annotations, attributes

I am working on a web application where different user roles should have different security rights (view, edit). In order to implement this, I have a custom attribute [ReadOnlyAuthorize("Supervisor, Administrator, SysAdministrator")].

When a field is marked with this attribute and the user does not have one of these roles, my editor templates mark the field as readonly and disabled.

The problem is that by using the same model in create, edit and search operations, I get the same functionality and this is not what I want. This looks really bad but it is a temporary solution.

Is there a way to override these annotations besides by using new and defining new attributes?

I hope this description makes sense to you, these are parts of my classes:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(AssetMetadata))]
public partial class DTAsset
{
}

public class AssetMetadata
{
    [ReadOnlyAuthorize("SysAdministrator")]
    [DisplayName("Asset ID:")]
    public string AssetID { get; set; }
}

public class AssetSearchViewModel : AssetMetadata
{
    // removed [ReadOnlyAuthorize("SysAdministrator")]
    [DisplayName("Asset ID:")]
    public string AssetID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have the authorizations on the model, and not in the controller?

Comment: You could use abstract class for AssetMetadata and interfaces to realize the functionality you need only in the viewmodels you desire.

Comment: @RonBeyer I do not know which is the best practice for something like that. It seemed like a good way and non invasive to do it like that.

Comment: You can always check what role the user has when the controller action is invoked, I'd avoid trying to "generate" different code based on the role of the current user.

Comment: @Gnqz Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @RonBeyer Yes, but that would probably mean that I would have to create a different view for every role.

Comment: Are you using Razor views?